# How to return &T or Ref<T> from a trait method

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a `trait` that *returns a reference to a string*.

In one structure that implements the trait,  I hold a `String`.  From this I can return a `&str`

In another structure that implements the trait,  I hold a `RefCell<String>`.  From this I can return a `Ref<str>`.

The only signature I have found to accommodate both types is the following (A `boxed Deref trait`):

```rust
   trait Get<'a> {
        fn get(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Deref<Target=str> + 'a>;
    }
```

```rust
struct A {
        name: String,
    }

impl<'a> Get<'a> for A {
        fn get(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Deref<Target=str> + 'a> {
            Box::new(self.name.as_str())
        }
    }

struct B {
        name: RefCell<String>,
    }

impl<'a> Get<'a> for B {
        fn get(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Deref<Target=str> + 'a> {
            let ret = Ref::map(self.name.borrow(), |it| it.as_str());
            Box::new(ret)
        }
    }
```

Not only is this incredibly ugly, but now I also need to call `deref()` twice, once for the `Box` and once for the `trait`.

```rust
#[test]
fn test_ref() {
        let a = A {
            name: "Woolly".to_string()
        };
        let b = B {
            name: RefCell::new("Woolly".to_string())
        };
        assert_eq!(a.get().deref().deref(), "Woolly");
        assert_eq!(b.get().deref().deref(), "Woolly");
    }
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3adcc1d369989d66dfd8d39de06bfdda)

Comment: You don't need to call `deref()` twice, the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No it does not do it.  I tried.

Comment: Maybe not in this case, but in general (e.g. calling a method on the type) it will.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman comment it out on the playground and see.  I added playground link to question.

Comment: Yes, because there are trait bounds here. But see e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e2958bdb41217bd225887c6b3fb4b64, you can call methods without `deref()`.

Comment: It seems like `&*a.get()` should work too, but same problem.

Comment: `&**a.get()` (two asterisks, not one).

Comment: LOL thats the double deref again.  My point.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce an associated type to use as the return.

```rs
trait Get {
    type Ret<'a>: Deref<Target = str> + 'a
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn get<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Ret<'a>;
}
```

The rest of your code can be changed like so.

```rs
struct A {
    name: String,
}

impl Get for A {
    type Ret<'a> = &'a str;
    fn get<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Ret<'a> {
        self.name.as_str()
    }
}

struct B {
    name: RefCell<String>,
}

impl Get for B {
    type Ret<'a> = Ref<'a, str>;
    fn get<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Ret<'a> {
        Ref::map(self.name.borrow(), |it| it.as_str())
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_ref() {
    let a = A {
        name: "Woolly".to_string(),
    };
    let b = B {
        name: RefCell::new("Woolly".to_string()),
    };
    assert_eq!(&*a.get(), "Woolly");
    assert_eq!(&*b.get(), "Woolly");
}
```

This works for your given test and should usually be sufficient, but if you want to unify the types like in this test:

```rs
#[test]
fn test_ref2() {
    let a = A {
        name: "Woolly".to_string(),
    };
    let b = B {
        name: RefCell::new("Woolly".to_string()),
    };

    // error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
    let deref_str = if rand::random() {
        a.get()
    } else {
        b.get()
    };
    
    assert_eq!(&*deref_str, "Woolly");
}
```

Then you will need to reintroduce the trait object or an enum.

```rs
#[test]
fn test_ref2() {
    let a = A {
        name: "Woolly".to_string(),
    };
    let b = B {
        name: RefCell::new("Woolly".to_string()),
    };

    let deref_str: Box<dyn Deref<Target = str>> = if rand::random() {
        Box::new(a.get())
    } else {
        Box::new(b.get())
    };

    assert_eq!(&**deref_str, "Woolly");
}

#[test]
fn test_ref3() {
    enum StrOrRef<'a> {
        Str(&'a str),
        Ref(Ref<'a, str>),
    }

    impl Deref for StrOrRef<'_> {
        type Target = str;
        fn deref(&self) -> &str {
            match self {
                Self::Str(s) => s,
                Self::Ref(r) => &*r,
            }
        }
    }

    let a = A {
        name: "Woolly".to_string(),
    };
    let b = B {
        name: RefCell::new("Woolly".to_string()),
    };

    let deref_str = if rand::random() {
        StrOrRef::Str(a.get())
    } else {
        StrOrRef::Ref(b.get())
    };

    assert_eq!(&*deref_str, "Woolly");
}
```

Another thing you could do is change the impls of `A` and `B` to use `type Ret<'a> = StrOrRef<'a>`.

Any of these is probably better than having the trait method return a `Box`, since it allows the trait to be flexible.

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9589b91e900847f83c247ae4159dff99)